# Best practices on connecting multiple angular apps?

Tags: php, angular

I have a web application composed of several Angular Applications. I have set them up run on the same domain and in each app I maintain the navigation to look the same even though they are technically in three different projects. Is there a better way to do this?

I have a PHP project with a dashboard and a navbar. The navbar contains three links. One to each of the Angular applications(chat, admin, etc). In each of the Angular applications I create a header component that mirrors the navbar in the php application. I do this so it feels like one large application. Is there a better way to do this or some best practice that describes the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The Angular CLI supports multiple applications in the same project. You could rewrite your php app in angular and create one large project that contains multiple Angular applications.

https://yakovfain.com/2017/04/06/angular-cli-multiple-apps-in-the-same-project/